# During c++ linking, library not found in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

When I build a simple program linking `pthread`, I got a strange problem:

When putting the `-lpthread` parameter before the source file, it fails to build and returns

> ld returned 1 exit status

However, it succeeds to build the program when I write the `-lpthread` parameter at last.

I am a newbie, sorry that I cannot upload an image. Following are two version commands:

**failed**: `gcc **-lpthread** maintest.cpp`

**successed**: `gcc maintest.cpp **-lpthead**`

I encountered the same problem in Ubuntu 11.04 before, but I could not reproduce the problem in Ubuntu 10.10.

I am not sure whether this is a bug in newer Ubuntu or just a constrain for normalizing Makefile?

Comment: you can upload an image to any sharing service, get direct link and embed it here through image tag

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly interesting.

I am on Linux Mint 12 and both of them seem to be working for me.

Did you try it out with a .c file and not with a cpp? Can you do that and post your result? (I am quite sure this doesn't make a difference, but just want to check!)

I am not a 100% sure, but I am quite positive that it cannot be a constraint for normalizing makefile because in linux, you do not need to have the correct extension for a file to be compiled with the right compiler. (That's why I am quite sure of the above statement). The compiler that is being used. So logically, it doesn't make any sense to constrain it given that pthread would just be loaded by the compiler ( library would be linked) and then it can jump to compiling the source. IF I am not wrong (correct me someone, if I am!), then essentially it won't make a difference because the flag being positioned anywhere in the command, would load/link the libary before compiling the source file.

So my bet would be on the bug, but I dont have a source to back me up. It's just what logical interpretation says! ( Correct me if I am wrong..again!)